# Difference betweem Maven jvmarg and jvm args command

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

What difference between pom.xml jvmargs and java plain args?

Hi,

I want know abount what's difference betwwen

```
   <plugin>
        <groupid>org.springframework.boot</groupid>
        <artifactid>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactid>
        <configuration>
            <jvmarguments>
                -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
            </jvmarguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

and

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m runnable.jar
```

Some people told me use both of them,

Is that necessary?

Comment: The configuration inside the plugin is applied whenever you use maven to start your application (either from your IDE or from the command line: "mvn spring-boot:run"). However, once the jar has been generated and you want to run it from the command line. Then you need to state the parameters in the command line.  You can find here a better explanation: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-run-maven-vs-executable-jar